# LINQ - How to change value in select or foreach loop?

Tags: c#, linq

```
IQueryable items = from rr in _dt.AllItems
                   where rr.ID == ItemID
                   select new{rr.Item, rr.SecondItem};
```

SecondItem is returning false or true. Is it possible to replace with different string values (for example with On and Off) and add to the items (IQueryable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found out. I'm using in my SQL database column a bit type (true or false). When I‘m selecting with LINQ I need to replace with the ("On" or "Off") values.
The code below meets my needs

```
IQueryable items = from rr in _dt.AllItems
               where rr.ID == ItemID
               select new {
                   rr.Item,
                   SecondItem = rr.SecondItem.Value ? "On" : "Off"
               };
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
IQueryable items = from rr in _dt.AllItems
               where rr.ID == ItemID
               select new {
                   rr.Item,
                   SecondItem = rr.SecondItem.HasValue ? "Off" : rr.SecondItem ? "On" : "Off"
               };
```

Comment: Thank you it looks like it works. I am not sure because I realized that I am storing this value as a bit (0 or 1) for some reason its always returning false(even if its 1 or 0). Any ideas?

Comment: OK, I found out. It works this way - (SecondItem = rr.SecondItem.Value ? "On" : "Off")

Comment: @Eugene: Be careful about just doing rr.SecondItem.Value.  The whole idea behind the Nullable<T> struct is that there may not be a value (highly unlikely in your case, since you're getting data from a bit field).

Comment: Ok I see, but in my case it will be false if not true and backward. Thank you

Comment: @Eugene: it can be false, true, and **null**.  That's why Marek Karbarz's example checks the HasValue property (in case it is null).

Answer (score 1):

You mean like

```
  var items = from rr in _dt.AllItems 
              where rr.ID == ItemID 
              select new
              {
                  rr.Item, 
                  rr.SecondItem == true ? "On" : "Off"
              };
```

Comment: Thank you guys for quick response. I tried both ways and I got the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Nullable<bool>' to 'bool'"? Do you know work around?

Comment: See my edit - since SecondItem is nullable you first have to check if it has value (is not null) and then use it.

Comment: @Marek Karbarz: You don't need to do a HasValue check since the Nullable struct overrides the Equals method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7b1e4z6%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).